# I Couldn't change HTTP headers in a NextJS project

Tags: http, next.js

As explained in the NextJs documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/headers , it is possible to configure the HTTP headers of a page using the code below, however my code is not working.

Next Example:

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/about',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'x-custom-header',
            value: 'my custom header value',
          },
          {
            key: 'x-another-custom-header',
            value: 'my other custom header value',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

My Code:

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/about',
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'cache-control',
            value: 'max-age=31536000',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

Comment: If you are on Next.js@9.5 and your header is not being set, it is because header cache is disable on dev environment